# Telecommunication app database design

Tags: sql, telecommunication, nosql

I would just like to ask or get a few expert advices/directions on building a database and architecture for a telecommunication app.

Basiclly there are 3 parts:

Switch (low level, calls, signaling)
Backend (CRM)
Mobile

Mostly focused now on the backend part so would like to know if anyone had some experience and would be able to point in some directions for research and so on. Nothing special, things like SQL or NoSQL and just some good points where I could learn and research more! Thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have worked for both Intergraph and Ericsson on their telecommunications apps and can suggest a few places for you to start your research.

## Domain

The telecom domain is very large, so I would suggest you determine what your audience wants you to focus on first.  Are you interested in facilities management, which is where poles, lines, and equipment are located?  Are you interested in logical network management, where you are worried less about the physical cables themselves and worried more about the logical circuits that "ride" these physical media?  Narrowing your domain will help you tremendously.

There are quite a few resources online, but I would suggest a reference, like this one: [Fundamentals of Telecom Book](http://www.ie.itcr.ac.cr/acotoc/Maestria_en_Computacion/Sistemas_de_Comunicacion_II/Material/Biblio5.pdf)

Do your best to research and know your domain.

## Data Modeling

For telecom data modeling, check out ESRI at [www.esri.com](http://www.ie.itcr.ac.cr/acotoc/Maestria_en_Computacion/Sistemas_de_Comunicacion_II/Material/Biblio5.pdf).  They specifically publish a telecom data model white paper that you might want to check out (you'll have to register to see it) at: [http://downloads2.esri.com/support/TechArticles/Telecommunications_Data_Model.pdf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory)

Also, check out the offerings from IBM at: [https://www-01.ibm.com/marketing/iwm/iwm/web/signup.do?source=sw-infomgt&S_PKG=500019725&S_CMP=is_bro11&S_TACT=109HF36W][3]

Finally, check out the products from Intergraph, Smallworld, and 3-GIS at:

- http://www.intergraph.com/communications/
- http://www.gedigitalenergy.com/geospatial/catalog/smallworld_network.htm
- http://www.3-gis.com/

## Graphs

My final bit of advice to you is to know your [graph theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory).  Modeling telecom networks requires advanced knowledge of node-edge, edge-edge, and directed graphs.  You need this knowledge to model pole-line graphs, underground duct networks, cable sheath-to-sheath connections, fiber and copper stand-to-strand and pair-to-pair connections, and the relationships between various parts of the network.

Beyond the relationships that you model with graphs, you will employ this knowledge to trace networks quickly.